# Reducing a dataframe to the most frequent combinations of two columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a json file which I import using the following code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('GPS').config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("SensorData.json")
```

The result is a dataframe similar to this:

```
+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  3|
|  1|  2|
|  3|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  1|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

My task is using PySpark  to reduce the data to only the most frequent combinations of two columns (A and B)

So the wanted output is this

```
+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  2|    3|
|  2|  1|    2|
+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a combination of groupBy and limit:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('GPS').config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("SensorData.json")

df.groupBy("A","B")
  .count()
  .sort("count",ascending = False)
  .limit(2)
  .show()
+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  2|    3|
|  2|  1|    2|
+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: But I have big data and cannot do it manually. Also, I have to run it in spark for efficiency

Comment: Yes, I have it in a data frame but didn't do any SQL

Comment: Thank you. This works but please correct me if wrong. I think it is not happening in Spark (but inside python). This way, I don't get the full performance benefit from Spark.

Comment: No once your data has been converted into a dataframe it is parallelized and it is executed in Spark.

Comment: You can check with the following code 

if isinstance(df, DataFrame):
        print("DataFrame")